# How to handle incoming protobuf message

Tags: c#, tcp, protobuf-net

Using TCPClient's NetworkStream and protobuf-net I send and receive protobuf messages via TCP.

Saw a similar question: [How to properly handle incoming protobuf message with a NetworkStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957210/how-to-properly-handle-incoming-protobuf-message-with-a-networkstream)

But in my case there can only be one message type so i dont think i need a resolver.

So i serialized my object and send it using tcp/ip, on my server i try to deserialize it and get io exception: Unable to read data from the transport connection.

Client:

```
...
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    Serializer.Serialize(ms, person);

    data = ms.ToArray();
}
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Server:

```
...
Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
String data = null;

while(true) 
{
    Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();            
    Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

    data = null;

    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    Person newPerson = Serializer.Deserialize<Person>(stream);<--- exeption
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the short version here is: use `SerializeWithLengthPrefix` and `DeserializeWithLengthPrefix`. The default protobuf behaviour is "read to the end of the stream". You shouldn't need the `MemoryStream` when serializing, btw; you should be fine to `Serialize` directly to the `NetworkStream`. If you need the `MemoryStream` for other reasons, you can save yourself a copy of the data by using:

```
stream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
```